# How do I align money values in table column to decimal point

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm in progress of creating an order summary table, which shows detailed insight into values, taxes etc. Every product is stored in it's own row. How do I align data so that the prices decimals are lined up horizontally, relative to the dot?

Example:

```
Product A    156.45
Product B      5.56
Product C     47.00
```

Comment: Is `text-align: right;` not working for you? Are your cents of variable number of digits?

Comment: Actually I put some additional data after cents and then this method fails.

Comment: Fair enough! I thought so.